# setState doesn't update all state properties after call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The thing is, that I use setState to update state.n and state.data. I want to call setState onClick, using handler. After calling setState, I perform a callback console.log to watch the changed state properties, but only state.data is changed, not state.n.

```js
handler(e) {
    this.setState((state) => {
        let arr = state.data;
        arr.push(fakeTableData[state.n+1]);
        this.setState({n: state.n+1, data: arr});
    }, console.log.bind(null, this.state.n));
}
```

After one handler used, I expect to see state.n incremented, but I had only state.data changed, not state.n. And I recieve a warning, like this: "Warning: An update (setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate) was scheduled from inside an update function. Update functions should be pure, with zero side-effects. Consider using componentDidUpdate or a callback." I've read a tutorial on the main react site, but there not enough info.

Comment: last line should be console.log.bind(this, this.state.n)

Answer (score 2):

You should not use setState inside function that sets state. That is why you got an error. Instead you should return state. Try this:

```
handler = (e) => {
    this.setState((state) => {
        let arr = state.data;
        arr.push(fakeTableData[state.n+1]);
        return {n: state.n+1, data: arr};
    }, () => { console.log(this.state.n) });
}
```

Comment: Provide an explanation as to why solution should be tried. `"Try this"` is meaningless

Comment: I tried to use return, it's my bad to call setState in setState, but I have the same result, state.n don't want to be updated.

Comment: @user2923317 your log is binding before setState occurs and you are misinterpreting the issue as a result

Comment: Can you try to use `() => {console.log(this.state.n)}` instead of `console.log.bind(this, this.state.n)` ? I realised that if you do binding with console.log it actually refers to old state. I tried this code in local environment and it works. Can you maybe paste some more relevant code from your component ?

Comment: @charlietfl thank you, I see it. It was my fault to setState instead return.

Comment: @SimoMatavulj y r right - using arrow function it works great!

Answer (score 2):

let's try `let arr = [...state.data]`